# Selecting MIN and MAX for a collection, based on an ActiveRecord scope, in one SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I would like to run the following query:

```sql
/* Inside a heredoc */
SELECT
  MIN("books"."page_count") AS min,
  MAX("books"."page_count") AS max
FROM "books"
  WHERE "books"."author_id" IN (#{authors.pluck(:id).map { |id| "'#{id}'" }.join(",")})
  AND "books"."publisher_id" IN (#{publishers.pluck(:id).map { |id| "'#{id}'" }.join(",")});
```

But instead of having to manually write the `WHERE` clauses at the end with that ugly interpolation, I'd like to use scopes I've defined on `Book`, something like:

```ruby
query = Book.by_author(authors).by_publisher(publishers).select('MIN("books"."page_count") as min, MAX("books"."page_count") as max').first
attrs = [query["min"], query["max"]]
```

I understand that this doesn't work because `Book.my_scope...` expects to return a collection of books, while I'm looking for numeric values.

I am aware I could do e.g.:

```ruby
query = Book.by_author(authors).by_publisher(publishers)
attrs = [query.minimum(:page_count), query.maximum(:page_count)]
```

But this results in two SQL queries, which seems quite unnecessary.

Is there a Rails-y way I can do this while keeping the flexibility of chainable scopes, without heredoc interpolation, and in one SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define it as a `class method`:

```rb
class Book
  class << self
    def minmax_page_count
      count = select('MIN(page_count) OVER (), MAX(page_count) OVER ()').take
       
      [count.min, count.max]
    end  
  end
end

Book.by_author(authors).by_publisher(publishers).minmax_page_count # => [1, 2]
```